# Dealing with the example.cpp in CRF++ toolkit

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, nlp

I am just starting to learn about the use of CRF++ toolkit.
I downloaded the linux version of [CRF++ 0.54](http://crfpp.sourceforge.net/) ,
When i try to compile the example.cpp under sdk/ with the command
g++ -o example example.cpp 
there comes the problem:

hpl@hpl-desktop:~/Documents/CRF/CRF++-0.54$ g++ -o a example.cpp 
/tmp/ccmJQgGu.o: In function `main':
example.cpp:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to`CRFPP::createTagger(char const*)'
example.cpp:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `CRFPP::getTaggerError()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to make the program run.

David

Answer (score 1):

The 4th line in example.cpp says: // c++ -O3 example.cpp -lcrfpp

Why don't you try that?

Comment: hpl@hpl-desktop:~/Documents/CRF/CRF++-0.54/sdk$ c++ -O3 example.cpp -l crfpp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrfpp 
it doen't work. Do i have to write the Makefile?

Comment: Did you build the library by entering ./configure and then make?